# Can I set Monaco Editor to highlight errors in C code?

Tags: monaco-editor, react-monaco-editor

I'm using Monaco Editor in a React app, instantiating it like this:

```
<Editor
 height="70vh"
 defaultLanguage="C"
 value={myCode}
 onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

If I set "defaultLanguage" to "javascript" then it validates whatever I type in and it highlights anything that's not proper javaScript in red.  However, I want to be able to validate C code, but when I change defaultLanguage to "C" it doesn't highlight any errors.  It still allows me to hit CTRL-space to see suggestions etc, but if I type in nonsense it doesn't highlight it.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monaco comes with a number of languages that have base support and a couple of them with full support. Javascript, Typescript, CSS, HTML and JSON belong to the second category. Check the node module folder monaco-editor/esm/vs which has a folder `basic-languages` and a folder `language`. The basic language support only comprises syntax highlighting. For more functionality you have to write an own parser and handle editor content change by that. Though this is a pretty big topic, not well suited for a single Q&A post.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know.  I don't think I want to write my own parser, so syntax highlighting will be enough for now!